# IOS Good practise to login using facebook and twitter

Tags: iphone, facebook

we are developing a platform with web and one iphone application. We have our own system for authentication but we want to improve it in order to support facebook and twitter login.

Through the web we haven't any problems, but through the mobile application we don't know how to manage correctly the facebook login and we don't find any tutorial or cookbook that explains what are the steps to do it in a good way.

Should the iphone application request the token from facebook and then send it to the server? Or is better take the facebook_id and then send it? Since we don't want to have two different accounts for the same person, is it necessary to check if the emails is already in database?

Any help would be much appreciate or at least one guide / tutorial in order to read about this topic.

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/) that I found useful:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Any help would be much appreciate or at least one guide / tutorial in order to read about this topic."

For the Facebook authentication for iOS, see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/authentication/

Comment: +1 This is helpful. Do you know of any docs that explain the correct configuration of the FB App?